# code for extracting and loading value to the userform

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to write a code that will extract value from the database where it is stored, load the value in the user form for editing purposes. The values from the database are stored as a " multi-line " cell entry. and here's the code im stuck on.

```
Private Sub cmd_Continue_Click()

Dim TargetRow As Integer

TargetRow = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(ColumnC_Menu, Sheets("Data").Range("Dyn_Business_Name_Website"), 0)

MsgBox (TargetRow)

End Sub
```

Here's the Code from the main Userform:

```
Private Sub cmd_Submit_Click()
'When we click Submit button'

Dim TargetRow As Integer 'variable for position control
Dim BusinessName As String

TargetRow = Sheets("Engine").Range("B3").Value + 1 'make variable equal to COUNTA formula on worksheet +1

BusinessName = Txt_BusinessName & vbNewLine & Txt_Website

If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Sheets("Data").Range("Dyn_Business_Name_Website"), BusinessName) > 0 Then

MsgBox ("Name Already Exists"), 0, "Check!"
Exit Sub
End If

'Begin Input into the data'
Sheets("Data").Range("Data_Start").Offset(TargetRow, 0).Value = Txt_Rank
Sheets("Data").Range("Data_Start").Offset(TargetRow, 1).Value = Txt_BusinessName & vbNewLine & Txt_Website
Sheets("Data").Range("Data_Start").Offset(TargetRow, 2).Value = Txt_Address & vbNewLine & Txt_Phone
```

Comment: You provided us with what you _want to do_, but we still don't know why your code isn't working. Are you receiving unexpected results? Any errors? If so, what line? Which code block doesn't work?

Comment: Yes I'm receiving a run-time error 1004 on the first code"(TargetRow = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(ColumnC_Menu, Sheets("Data").Range("Dyn_Business_Name_Website"), 0) )"
but the same code works well on a different database.

Comment: Well, you could start some debugging: when hitting the error, click “Debug” button and then in the Immediate Window (CTRL-G to pop it out) type: ?Sheets("Data").Range("Dyn_Business_Name_Website").Address and press return to see if you get the expected range

Comment: And what is that ‘ColumnC_Menu’ and where does it get defined?  Moreover, change ‘Dim TargetRow As Integer’ to ‘Dim TargetRow As Long’ and avoid possible overflow issues with rows index greater than some 32767 or so

Comment: ColumnC_Menu is a combobox that's populate by a dynamic range on column C

Comment: even with the TargetRow as Long i keep getting the same error.